# ModuleNotFoundError: no module named efficientnet.tfkeras

Tags: python, keras

I attempted to do `import segmentation_models as sm`, but I got an error saying `efficientnet` was not found. So I then did `pip install efficientnet` and tried it again. I now get `ModuleNotFoundError: no module named efficientnet.tfkeras`, even though Keras is installed as I'm able to do `from keras.models import *` or anything else with Keras

how can I get rid of this error?

Comment: Do you have tensorflow installed?

Comment: yes I already have it

Comment: How exactly did you install segmentation_models?

Comment: I believe I did `pip install -U segmentation-models` from https://github.com/qubvel/segmentation_models

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To install segmentation-models use the following command: `pip install git+https://github.com/qubvel/segmentation_models`